# React Ternary Operator Prevent Repeating Code with Styled components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So I'm using styled components and found the only way to trigger my function is with a ternary operator that wraps my entire navbar component. The problem is I have to recopy the entire component code into the `:` statement which basically means I'm writing my nav component code twice just to get the ternary to work properly.

Is there a way to not repeat it and write the ternary with the least amount of code?

So here's my code issue

```
  return (
    <>
     // If scroll is true, I want to add this active prop onto my <Nav>
        {scroll ? (
          <Nav active click={click}>
            <NavbarContainer>
              <NavLogo to="/" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <NavIcon />
                EXPLOR
              </NavLogo>
              <MobileIcon onClick={handleClick}>
                {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
              </MobileIcon>
              <NavMenu onClick={handleClick} click={click}>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/">Home</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/images">Images</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/products">Products</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
        </Nav>

       : 

         // If the scroll is false, I remove the active prop from my nav
         (
          <Nav click={click}>
            <NavbarContainer>
              <NavLogo to="/" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                <NavIcon />
                EXPLOR
              </NavLogo>
              <MobileIcon onClick={handleClick}>
                {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
              </MobileIcon>
              <NavMenu onClick={handleClick} click={click}>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/">Home</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/images">Images</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <NavLinks to="/products">Products</NavLinks>
                </NavItem>
        </Nav>
    }
 </>
```

The whole point is so I can trigger this active prop from my styled component

```
    background: ${({ active }) => (active ? "#141414" : "transparent")};
```

But as you can see I had to copy my entire component code twice because the `<Nav>` that has the active prop wraps around my entire code.

Is there an easier way to toggle the active prop with styled components without having to recopy my entire navbar in the `:` or statement?

Comment: It looks like you can put this on codesandbox, can you do that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming active is a booelan you can smply set active={scroll } like so

```
 <Nav active={scroll} click={click}>
    .....
 </Nav>
```